# Adding initial content to Plone CMS

Tags: plone

I'm looking for the best way to import initial content into Plone 4.2. Requirements:

- being able to use the initial content in tests
- being able to import initial content TTW
- supports content, users and groups
- easy way to modify initial content population

Does such product exist?

Comment: GenericSetup profiles have some kind of content import. Don't use them. They work really bad. For tests, just create content by hand using invokeFactory() and such.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Dexterity content, Shuttle Thread has a great blog post explaining how to use [transmogrify.dexterity](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/transmogrify.dexterity) for initial content imports: http://shuttlethread.com/blog/development-with-transmogrify.dexterity

Comment: Looks promising, does it support users/groups?

Comment: @iElectric You'd need to add other sections to your transmogrifier pipeline. Maybe [collective.blueprint.usersandgroups](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/collective.blueprint.usersandgroups)?